# How to get data from a "packed_transaction"?

Tags: transactions

I am trying to extract the data out of a packed transaction.  Specifically, I am reading a `proposal` from the `eosio.msig` table and trying to get the data from the proposed multisig transaction to validate it.

Here's the code

```
   eosio::multisig::proposals proptable( "eosio.msig"_n, proposer.value );
   auto& prop = proptable.get( proposal_name.value, "proposal not found" );
```

where now `prop.packed_transaction` holds the packed transaction.

I think I might need to use `prop.packed_transaction.data()` but I am not sure what this is returning and I can't find any documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example reading token transfer data out of a transaction

```
void myaction() {

   struct token_transfer {
      name from;
      name to;
      asset quantity;
      string memo;
   };

   // transaction is inside "prop" object (that we get from a eosio.msig table)
   eosio::multisig::proposals proptable( "eosio.msig"_n, proposer.value );
   auto& prop = proptable.get( proposal_name.value, "proposal not found" );

   // get the first action in the transaction, remember transactions can have multiple actions
   eosio::action my_action = eosio::unpack<eosio::transaction>( prop.packed_transaction ).actions.front();

   // get the data out of the action
   token_transfer my_action_data = my_action.data_as<token_transfer>();

   const name from      = my_action_data.from;
   const name to        = my_action_data.to;
   const asset quantity = my_action_data.quantity;
   const string memo    = my_action_data.memo;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Havn't tried myself but i think you can use one of the `Unpack<T>(...)`-functions from [datastream-library](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosio.cdt/blob/master/libraries/eosiolib/datastream.hpp#L1293)  - as long as you know Type T.

something like the following:

```
auto unpackedProposal = unpack<knownProposalType>( prop.packed_transaction.data );
```